# How to convert xls to xlsx in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel for downloading the file as xlsx format. I am using codeigniter framework. Previously i am downloading xls format. At that time the file is downloaded successfully. If i am trying for downloading as xlsx format it gives the error as below image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02GE9.png)

My code is :

```
$this->load->library('Excel');
$this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Sales Data'); 
$filename='Salesdata.xlsx';
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel2007');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition:attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

There is no error when i am adding as xls format. It gives the error when i am adding as filename.xlsx. Any solution please.

Answer (score 0):

you may continue with [php Output buffers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [codeigniter download helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/download_helper.html)
for example :-

```
$filename='Salesdata.xlsx';
ob_start();
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel2007');
//force user to download the Excel file without writing it to server's HD
$objWriter->save('php://output');
$this->load->helper('download');
$excelFileContents = ob_get_clean();
force_download($filename, $excelFileContents);
```

Comment: I was copied the code above and tried but no luck. It gives the same message. Is there any problem with my PhpExcel?